# How to use variable instead of query in MySQL command

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using the below command to get data from a database;

```
mysql --ssl -Ns -h {{ db_addr }} -t -u {{ db_user }} -p'{{ db_password }}' database_name -e "'describe table22;'"
```

But now I am getting `describe table22;` inside variable `db_query`
and I am not sure how to use this variable `db_query` inside the same command.

I am trying below command but not getting the required output.

`mysql --ssl -Ns -h {{ db_addr }} -t -u {{ db_user }} -p'{{ db_password }}' database_name -e "$db_query"`

Comment: I recommend asking what your end outcome is. There are better ways than parsing `describe table22` output like using the [information_schema.COLUMNS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-schema-columns-table.html) table.

Comment: Existing command giving me required output:
`mysql --ssl -Ns -h {{ db_addr }} -t -u {{ db_user }} -p'{{ db_password }}' database_name -e "'describe table22;'"`

Comment: Please add all such clarification to your question by editing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysql --ssl -Ns -h {{ db_addr }} -t -u {{ db_user }} -p'{{ db_password }}' identityiq -e "{{ db_query }}"`
Is working fine for me.
So db_query is the variable collecting sql query from the user and we are passing it in the command to get the output.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it